# What would happen if all water on earth including the oceans was placed evenly over the atmosphere of Earth?

Tags: gravity, earth, tidal-forces, water

Would that massive water body sit on top of the atmospheric bubble or would it fall to the ground? Would it rain water or fire instead? Would we see the skyes red instead of blue? What would be the pressure on the surface of earth? would tha pressure be enough to liquify the atmosphere?

Comment: I've voted to close.  There are multiple questions here.  In short, it would fall to the ground in a deluge.  More generally "what if (some weird hypothetical situation that could never occur)" questions are not really answerable.

Comment: It falls down like rain and stones